The password deletion and visibility icon is not displayed
app:endIconMode="clear_text"
app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
These attributes are not working, I used material:1.4.0. I changed the version and added icons manually, but still not working.
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editTextlgn"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:hint="Введите логин или почту"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.411" /\>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите пароль"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextlgn" />


This is MaterialUI edittext. Change layout_width & layout_height as your need.
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textEmail"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:hint="Email"
    app:hintEnabled="true"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    app:hintTextColor="#ffff00"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#ffff00"
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#FF6D00"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorIconTint="@color/transparent"
    app:errorTextColor="#FF6D00"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.375"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_mail_outline_24">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textPassword"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="#00000000"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#ffff00"
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#ff0000"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconCheckable="false"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorIconTint="@color/transparent"
    app:hintTextColor="#ffff00"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

